# How to add remarks column using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have `dataFrame` as below and want to add remarks using Scala

```
id    val  visits 
111   2        1
111   2        1
112   4        2
112   5        4
113   6        1
```

Expected output should be below

```
id    val    visits   remarks
111   2        1      Ramdom
111   2        1      Ramdom
112   4        2      Less visit
112   5        4      More visit
113   6        1      One visit
```

Remarks should be:
**Ramdom** for Id has two records with same value & visits
**One Visit** for Id has only one record which contains any no of visits
**Less Visit** for Id has two records with less visits compared to other
**More Visit** for Id has more than one record with different value and visits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May not be the best solution but it's a working one:

First group your `dataFrame` by `val` and `visits` and the count of them

```
val grouped = df.groupBy("id").agg(max($"val").as("maxVal"), max($"visits").as("maxVisits"), min($"val").as("minVal"), min($"visits").as("minVisits"), count($"id").as("count"))
```

Then define a `UDF` where you implement your logic:

```
val remarks = functions.udf ((value: Int, visits: Int, maxValue: Int, maxVisits: Int, minValue: Int, minVisits: Int, count: Int) =>
   if (count == 1) {
     "One Visit"
   }else if (value == maxValue && value == minValue && visits == maxVisits && visits == minVisits) {
     "Random"
   }else {
     if (visits < maxVisits) {
       "Less Visits"
     }else {
       "More Visits"
     }
   }
 )
```

Then join the original `dataFrame` and the grouped one by `id` and add the desired column with the `UDF`. Finally remove the undesired columns from the output:

```
 df.join(grouped, Seq("id"))
   .withColumn("remarks", remarks($"val", $"visits", $"maxVal", $"maxVisits", $"minVal", $"minVisits", $"count"))
   .drop("maxVal","maxVisits", "minVal", "minVisits", "count")
```

Output:

```
+---+----+-------+-----------+
| id| val| visits|    remarks|
+---+----+-------+-----------+
|112|   4|      2|Less Visits|
|112|   5|      4|More Visits|
|113|   6|      1|  One Visit|
|111|   2|      1|     Random|
|111|   2|      1|     Random|
+---+----+-------+-----------+
```

P.S. remember to import functions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
```